# Yahoo Finance Stastics web scraping returns Garbage data

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

(Python) On trying to get [Stastics](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL) for stocks on Yahoo finance , the returned data is garbage .How to get back the actual html buffer / network data?

```
RESPONSE : "a020c8855031":"527765c1cbe2ec4a3f07d7dca263f067","567f8aa563f6":"da66cb3bc88b4e1bec0ac8605a6216df".........
```

CODE:

```
def get_stock_stats():
   headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'} stockSymbol = 'AAPL' url = 
   'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+ stockSymbol + '/key-statistics?p=' + stockSymbol 
   resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5).text
   resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
   print(resp)
get_stock_stats()
```